# Update json value from sql column value

Tags: json, sql-server

Using SQL Server, I want to take column data and copy it into a json object column

I am using SQL Server to a query a column and a json data. What I want to do is to copy the data in column `ename` to `fieldvalue` column in the code below. If I could do it using SQL that would be great.

```
SELECT 
    a.id, a.ssn, a.ename, p.CaptionName, p.FieldName, p.FieldType, p.FieldValue
FROM 
    tablename as a
CROSS APPLY 
    OPENJSON (details)
        WITH (CaptionName NVARCHAR(100),
              FieldName NVARCHAR(100),
              FieldType NVARCHAR(15),
              FieldValue NVARCHAR(50)) AS P
WHERE
    p.captionname = 'txtEname' 
    AND a.ssn = '000-00-0000'
```

My json string in the details column

```
[{"CaptionName":"txtEname","FieldName":null,"FieldType":null,"FieldValue":""}]
```

I'm really not that good with sql which is what i want to use. after copying the data to the json object i will remove the ename column.

Comment: I want to copy the value from column ename say "stackoverflow" and update the json array fieldvalue key. output would be  [{"CaptionName":"txtEname","FieldName":null,"FieldType":null,"FieldValue":"stackoverflow"}]

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Answer (score 4):

## UPDATE 2019-07-11

Here's an amended solution which works for scenarios when there are multiple values in the JSON: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1fde45dfb604b2d5540c56f6c17a822d

```sql
update a
set details = JSON_MODIFY(details, '$[' + x.[key] + '].FieldValue', ename)
from dbo.tblUissAssignments a
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (details, '$') x
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (x.Value)
    WITH (CaptionName NVARCHAR(100),
        FieldName NVARCHAR(100),
        FieldType NVARCHAR(15),
        FieldValue NVARCHAR(50)) AS P
WHERE a.ssn = '000-00-0000'
and p.CaptionName = 'txtEname'
```

This is similar to my original answer (see below).  However:

- We now have 2 `cross apply` statements.  The first is used to split the JSON array into elements, so we get a key (index) and value (JSON object as a string), as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#path
- The second does what your original CROSS APPLY did, only acting on the single array element.
- We use the `[key]` returned by the first `cross apply` to target the item in the array that we wish to update in our `JSON_MODIFY` statement.

NB: If it's possible for your JSON array to contain multiple objects that need updating, the best solution I can think of is to put the above statement into a loop; since 1 update will only update 1 index on a given JSON.  Here's an example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=120d2ac7dd3a024e5e503a5f64b0089e

```sql
declare @doWhileTrueFlag bit = 1

while (@doWhileTrueFlag = 1)
begin

    update a
    set details = JSON_MODIFY(details, '$[' + x.[key] + '].FieldValue', ename)
    from dbo.tblUissAssignments a
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (details, '$') x
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (x.Value)
        WITH (CaptionName NVARCHAR(100),
            FieldName NVARCHAR(100),
            FieldType NVARCHAR(15),
            FieldValue NVARCHAR(50)) AS P
    WHERE a.ssn = '000-00-0000'
    and p.CaptionName = 'txtEname'    
    and p.FieldValue != ename --if it's already got the correct value, don't update it again

    set @doWhileTrueFlag = case when @@RowCount > 0 then 1 else 0 end

end
```

---

## ORIGINAL ANSWER

Try this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b7b4d075cac6cd46239561ddb992ac90

```
update a
set details = JSON_MODIFY(details, '$[0].FieldValue', ename)
from dbo.tblUissAssignments a
cross apply
    OPENJSON (details)
        WITH (CaptionName NVARCHAR(100),
              FieldName NVARCHAR(100),
              FieldType NVARCHAR(15),
              FieldValue NVARCHAR(50)) AS P
where a.ssn = '000-00-0000'
and p.captionname = 'txtEname'
```

More info on the JSON_MODIFY method here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

The subtle bit is that you're updating a json array containing a json object; not a single object.  For that you have to include the index on the root element.  See this post for some useful info on JsonPath if you're unfamiliar: https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html

---

Regarding scenarios where there's multiple items in the array, ideally we'd use a filter expression, such as this:

```
update a
set details = JSON_MODIFY(details, '$[?(@.CaptionName == ''txtEname'')].FieldValue', ename)
from dbo.tblUissAssignments a
where a.ssn = '000-00-0000'
```

Sadly MS SQL doesn't yet support these (see this excellent post: https://modern-sql.com/blog/2017-06/whats-new-in-sql-2016)

As such, I think we need to apply a nasty hack.  Two such approaches spring to mind:

- Implement a loop to iterate through all matches
- Convert from JSON to some other type, then convert back to JSON afterwards

I'll think on these / whether there's something cleaner, since neither sits comfortably at present...

Comment: This worked well but updated the first index, what if in this array does not sit in the first  index all the time.[
        {"CaptionName":"txtCname","FieldName":null,"FieldType":null,"FieldValue":""},
        {"CaptionName":"txtEname","FieldName":null,"FieldType":null,"FieldValue":""}
        ]

Comment: @ElNottoWorry I'd hoped you didn't have that requirement given your sample data - I don't have an easy answer; see extended answer for my current thoughts...

Comment: Woo! Solved it in a nice way: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1fde45dfb604b2d5540c56f6c17a822d

Comment: even original answer works well, if my json was one array thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then one possible approach (if you use SQL Server 2017+) is to use `OPENJSON()` and string manipulations with `STRING_AGG()`:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   id int, 
   ssn varchar(12), 
   ename varchar(40),
   details nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   (id, ssn, ename, details)
VALUES
   (1, '000-00-0000', 'stackoverflow1', N'[{"CaptionName":"txtEname","FieldName":null,"FieldType":null,"FieldValue":""}, {"CaptionName":"txtEname","FieldName":null,"FieldType":null,"FieldValue":""}]'),
   (2, '000-00-0000', 'stackoverflow2', N'[{"CaptionName":"txtEname","FieldName":null,"FieldType":null,"FieldValue":""}, {"CaptionName":"txtEname","FieldName":null,"FieldType":null,"FieldValue":""}]')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT
   d.id, d.ssn, d.ename,
   CONCAT(N'[', STRING_AGG(JSON_MODIFY(j.[value], '$.FieldValue', ename), ','), N']') AS details
FROM #Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (d.details) j
WHERE JSON_VALUE(j.[value], '$.CaptionName') = N'txtEname' AND (d.ssn = '000-00-0000')   
GROUP BY d.id, d.ssn, d.ename
```

Output:

```
id  ssn         ename           details
1   000-00-0000 stackoverflow1  [{"CaptionName":"txtEname","FieldName":null,"FieldType":null,"FieldValue":"stackoverflow1"},{"CaptionName":"txtEname","FieldName":null,"FieldType":null,"FieldValue":"stackoverflow1"}]
2   000-00-0000 stackoverflow2  [{"CaptionName":"txtEname","FieldName":null,"FieldType":null,"FieldValue":"stackoverflow2"},{"CaptionName":"txtEname","FieldName":null,"FieldType":null,"FieldValue":"stackoverflow2"}]
```

For SQL Server 2016 you may use `FOR XML PATH` for string aggregation:

```
SELECT
   d.id, d.ssn, d.ename,
   CONCAT(N'[', STUFF(s.details, 1, 1, N''), N']') AS details
FROM #Data d
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT CONCAT(N',', JSON_MODIFY(j.[value], '$.FieldValue', ename))
   FROM #Data
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (details) j
   WHERE 
      (JSON_VALUE(j.[value], '$.CaptionName') = N'txtEname') AND
      (ssn = '000-00-0000') AND
      (id = d.id) AND (d.ssn = ssn) AND (d.ename = ename)
   FOR XML PATH('')
) s(details)
```

Comment: We are on SQL 2016, 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @ElNottoWorry Please, check updated answer. Thanks,